# If $G=H\rtimes K$ where $H$ is cyclic, and $K$ is abelian, why is $G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is a curious problem I've been stuck on.

> Suppose $G=H\rtimes K$, where $H$ is cyclic of order $n$, $K$ abelian with $\gcd(|K|,\varphi(n))=1$, $\varphi$ being the totient function. Why is $G$ actually abelian?

I let $h$ be a generator of $H$. Computing the product of two elements in two ways
$$
(h^i,k_1)(h^j,k_2)=(h^ik_1h^jk_1^{-1},k_1k_2)
$$
and
$$
(h^j,k_2)(h^i,k_1)=(h^jk_2h^ik_2^{-1},k_2k_1).
$$
Since $K$ is abelian, I just need to show the first entries are equal,
$$
h^ik_1h^jk_1^{-1}=h^jk_2h^ik_2^{-1}.
$$ 
I don't know where to go after that, and I don't see how to use the fact that $\gcd(|K|,\varphi(n))=1$. Does anyone see what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If $H\rtimes K$, then we know that it comes from some homomorphism $K\to\text{Aut}(H)$. Now since $H$ is cyclic we know that $|\text{Aut}(H)|=\varphi(|H|)$. So what has to be true about this homomorphism, and what does this tell us about the semidirect product?

Comment: Thanks Alex. The semidirect product comes from some homomorphism $f:K\to\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, where $f(k)$ is the conjugation by $k$ automorphism on $H$. So the order of $f(k)$ divides the order of $k$, thus divides $|K|$. Since the order of $f(k)$ also divides $\varphi(|H|)=\varphi(n)$, $f(k)$ has order $1$. So $f(k)=id$ for all $k$. So the semidirect product is actually direct?

Comment: @yunone Couldn't have said it better myself :)